# Are there any constants in Swing to indicate a big enough(or ignored) size of dimension(height or width)?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I'm new to java, and here's a question I can't find the answer in Java doc and Google.

In my case, I want wanna restrict the height(just height) of a panel(which nested in a panel with BoxLayout), so I add codes like below:

```
p2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(10000, 30));
```

It works fine until then.

The problem is that the numeric 10000 is some kid of ugly as you can see.

I want to know are there any constants to indicate a big enough number so I can replace the number 10000 with one of them. Or maybe are there any other better ways I can make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you could use [Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) like so,

```
p2.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 30));
```

There are many possible solutions, another is to use the Screen Height, for example

```
GraphicsDevice gd = 
    GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
int maxHeight = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
```

Comment: Thank you Frisch. I want to know(or make sure), aren't there any constants specific to Swing or size?

Comment: Probably more realistic and safe would be Byte.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ,I don't know why, but it seems Byte.MAX_VALUE does not work here. and, I wanna know why I should not ask this question here, so I can avoid next time.